# Kubernetes Cluster APP DNS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

If I have a domain name `www.domain.com` registered and I have fresh kubernetes cluster up and running. I have successfully lauched  `Deployments` and  `Services` to expose the requirements.

The service is creating a `LoadBalancer` on my GCE cluster and when I try to access my `APP` through the the external IP its working.

But this is what I wanted to achieve ideally :

To route all the traffic for my apps as  `www.app.domain.com` , `www.app2.domain.com`. Upon research I have found that I need an `Ingress Controller` preferably `NGINX` server, I have been try to do this and failing miserably.

This is the service exposing JSON for my deployments:

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": 'node-js-srv'
    },

    "spec": {
        "type": 'LoadBalancer',
        "label": {
            'app': 'node-js-srv'
        },

        "ports": [
        {
            "targetPort": 8080,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 80,
            "name": "http"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 443,
            "name": "https",
            "targetPort": 8080
        }
        ],
        "selector": {
            "app": 'node-js'
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of nginx do you not have working? A reverse proxy isn't that difficult

Comment: @cricket_007 I haven't been able to figure out how the ngnix lube deployment yaml should look like. I assuming 'customdomain.com' as my registered domain ....and having my apps load balance on 'app.customdomain.com' .... I am really new to the whole networking and dev ops ....

Comment: I'm not familiar with kubernetes, just nginx config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCE/GKE have already a `Ingress Controller` and you could use that one.

You must specify your service as type `NodePort`and create a ressource from type `Ingress`
See:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/

You find a example for GCE here https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/deployment/gce

Service:

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": 'node-js-srv'
    },

    "spec": {
        "type": 'NodePort',
        "label": {
            'app': 'node-js-srv'
        },

        "ports": [
        {
            "targetPort": 8080,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 80,
            "name": "http"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": 443,
            "name": "https",
            "targetPort": 8080
        }
        ],
        "selector": {
            "app": 'node-js'
        },
    }
}
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.app.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: node-js-srv
          servicePort: 80
  - host: www.app2.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: xyz
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Are you sure about the requirement for NodePort? It should work without the NodePort when using ingress-controller. Also, it may be more work required to setup DNS. The DNS records have to point to something exposed by the GCE/GKE cluster, either a load balancer IP or a CNAME. Not sure how Google solved this however...

Comment: On GCE/GKE NodePort is required see here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26508.

Comment: Ingress makes it easier to manage the DNS. The ingress creates a load balancer with an IP and you could create a wildcard DNS entry e.g. *.domain.com. Afterwards kubernetes routes the traffic to the correct service

Comment: It did work with NodePort in the service and updating the DNS wildcard with the subdomain routing. Just I more question, what if I want to use the same load balancer IP while creating other ingress ?

Comment: This is not possible and the questions is why you want to do it. On loadbalancer is equal one ingress. You could add all services to the one ingress. If you want to work with static ip's and want to assign the same ip to another ingress/LB after you delete the first ingress you could assign an static IP to the LB. Like this: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/static-ip/gce