# Kubernetes Subdomain for each service

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

How to add multiple ingress or Load balancers in kubernetes for separate services, 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591656/kubernetes-cluster-app-dns/42604912#42604912) is the post who I ended up creating a ingress to my sub-domain.  Is there any way we can specific the same IP address created by GCE to launch multiple Ingress resources.

I am using GCE for hosting my cluster. If there is a better way to handle this scenario to have multiple  resources to expose a service with a sub-domain `www.app1.domain.com`, `www.app2.domain.com` which are entirely different apps and have two ingress resources that point to  two these specific services using same external IP address.

From the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591656/kubernetes-cluster-app-dns/42604912#42604912) I could able to create but unable to specify the external IP address to it.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define multiple Ingress resources and put them to Kubernetes - they don't have to be in the same yaml file. All ingress resources share the same proxy and they are routed via the defined hostname and path to the wanted service.

I am not sure what you mean with the external IP address.

Comment: I was able to get this work by using a `ngnix loadbalancer` would be acting as external IP for all my servies and defining mulitple Ingress with `type NodePort` for each service, worked like charm.